# AngularJS - inserting HTML inside currently loaded view

Tags: angularjs

I have an HTML template that I need to insert on specific views, so I was wondering if this possible in AngularJS and if yes how? Any example is highly appreciated. Thanks

Note: I've checked ng-html but as far as I understood it binds HTML to a scope variable which I can access from view, but that is not applicable for me as the html template I am trying to inject is big and I would rather have it in a separate html file, example: divsToInsert.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're doing this from a controller; if so, you can use jQuery to insert [`ng-include`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) into your view in the right spot.

It's been a while since I had to do this, so I don't exactly remember, but I believe you will also have to wrap the `ng-include` in a call to [`$compile`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile)

EDIT: I found a code snippet from an old project that reminded me how to do this. You basically want to do the following:

```
$('some-html-identifier').append($compile("<ng-include src=\"'path/to/template.html'\"></ng-include>"));
```

The only think you have to do differently is inject `$compile` as a dependency to your controller.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing DOM manipulation inside the Controller, it's not a good practice.